# Calculate statistics before and after an event

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to compute statistics ( mean, median, and sum of firm scores) 3 years before and after a person became a CEO at a firm. A person can work as a CEO for multiple firms.
ceoYEAR is the year when he became a CEO.
scoreYEAR is the year when firm scores were measured.
In some observations, the scores are not available then it should return as NA.
The ouput data should have mean of scores 3 years before and 3 years after  the YearCEO.
I tried to split data by before and after events, then compute statistics by group by in library "dpylr". It works but takes many manual steps to finish. I am looking for more efficient methods to do so. Thanks!

```
ceoID = c("48195", "48195", "48195", "48195", "48195", "48195", 
"48195", "10203", "10203", "10203", "10203", "10203", "22879", 
"22879", "22879"), firmID = c("001004", "001004", "001004", "001004", 
"001004", "001004", "001004", "001013", "001013", "001013", "001013", 
"001013", "001013", "001013", "001013"), ceoYEAR = c(2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2001, 
2001, 2001), scoreYEAR = c(2003, 2004, 2013, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 1999, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 1999, 2001, 2002), scores = c(0, 
-2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1))
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your code *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it *for yourself*. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?  Also, please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: A nice way to share data is with `dput`. `dput(your_sample_data)` will create R code to reproduce `your_sample_data`, which can then be used to test solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I called your data `df`.
Is that what you meant? If so, add to `mutate` the median.

```
ceoID ceoYEAR firmID scores scoreYEAR mean_after mean_before
   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 48195    2018 001004      0      2015     NA           0    
 2 48195    2018 001004      0      2016     NA           0    
 3 48195    2018 001004      0      2017     NA           0    
 4 48195    2018 001004      0      2018     NA          NA    
 5 10203    2003 001013     -1      2001     NA          -0.25 
 6 10203    2003 001013     -1      2002     NA          -0.25 
 7 10203    2003 001013      0      2003     NA          NA    
 8 10203    2003 001013      1      2004     -0.25       NA    
 9 22879    2001 001013      0      1999     NA          -0.667
10 22879    2001 001013     -1      2001     NA          NA    
11 22879    2001 001013     -1      2002     -0.667      NA
```

The code:

```
 df |> 
  filter(between(scoreYEAR,ceoYEAR-3,ceoYEAR+3)) |> 
  group_by(ceoID,firmID) |> # filter can go away
  mutate(mean_after = ifelse(scoreYEAR > ceoYEAR,
                            mean(scores),NA),
        mean_before = ifelse(scoreYEAR < ceoYEAR,
                             mean(scores),NA))
```

Comment: Sorry. I see mean_after and mean_before are not accurate. For example, in the obs #5 and 6, the score before 2003 are -1 in year 2001 and year 2002. However, the mean computed is -0.25, it should be -1 instead. Thank you for your helps